# org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] Duplicate entry X for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, multithreading, activemq-classic

I am writing a back-end java code with `active-mq` in producer consumer model. When multiple consumers runs using and try to update in a table question the following exception is occured and the transaction is rollbacked. Multiple threads are running inside each consumer task.

```
WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000

07:10:31,609 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] Duplicate entry '69-947' for key 'PRIMARY'

07:10:31,615 ERROR [com.xminds.bestfriend.consumers.QuestionGeneration] Exception failed the Question generation 

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not insert: [com.xminds.bestfriend.frontend.model.Friendship];
```

Any one can suggest a solution for this.

Comment: `Duplicate entry '69-947' for key 'PRIMARY'` , it seems two threads are trying to insert a record with same `PK` ! How do you generate the `PK` ?

Comment: I am taking stream data from facebook for our application and inside the table post_id is used as primary key.

Comment: I want to know who generates the `PK` ? Is it auto generated or you provide the `PK` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your are trying to insert the record using existing primary key. Make sure the primary key is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You have a constraint in your database. Primary key in a table is duplicate, you should use an autogenerate id for your table

Comment: Facebook post_id is used as primary key,because in my application facebook stream data is stored in the table in hbm.xml it is give like the following <id name="id" type="string">
            <column name="id" length="100" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>

Comment: you should try with  <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
         <property name="post_id " type="string">
            <column name="post_id " length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>